# Create a pipeline jobs from single job jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I need to create a set of pipelines every month for the new version.
I want to set up a job that will create the Jenkins jobs with Jenkinsfile from the repo
It has to either trigger or run automatically and create a job w.r.t Jenkins file in a folder or workspace.
so that I don't have to access the server whenever I need to run a job

This way I can create the jobs of the new version and patches jobs.
Also, new views if needed. Dashboard I can manage but creating the number of similar jobs with a similar format is waste of time and resources, is there a way to automate it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and in particular ask a question at all. 

Comment: I have asked a question and gave a description w.r.t to the question. Is anything wrong?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry: _'is there a way to automate it.'_ is indeed a question. My bad; I was scanning for a `?`... ‍♂️

Comment: You've already tagged the question with [`jenkins-job-dsl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins-job-dsl), which is also what I'd try to go for. Where did you struggle with it?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for the mistake.
I am not good with grammar so I made a mistake

Also, I referred to the job-DSL plugin and it shows that I have to edit the configuration each time I need to add the job where I got confused.
I will have the jobs with the names of the parameters same but values will be wrong 
Like the choice parameter
I have to give 1 @ stage-1 and 2 @ stage-2
Which may trigger different sets of jobs with values and etc.,

Comment: Previously I have 10 to 12 like that so I have put manual effort to change the values and created the jobs separately

Now I am having a 2 to 3 new jobs a day so it takes so much time and effort

Comment: @orugantisivamuralikrishna You can actually write a Jenkinsfile in the root path or any path you can configure in the Jenkins job configure, and also add tag type with "Git parameter" plugin, which let you select and deploy your application or code with latest version or with specific tagged version.